# How to export attributes from more than one layer in QGIS3 to csv?

Tags: qgis, export, csv

I have two vector layers, one has geographical points and the other has polygons representing suburb boundaries. I want to export a list of all the points in a table with a column listing the suburb and postcode in which the points are located.

Comment: Hi Reinier, have you tried Data Management Tools under the Vector menu - there is an option to join attributes by location - you can join your polygon layer to your points layer which will create a new layer which contains attributes from both?

Comment: Yes I have, didn't work initially when using the point layer as the input file. Made the polygon layer the input now and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.